# When i add app priv-app phone not booting

Tags: android, android-source, prebuild

I have been trying to add a apk to priv-app.

Following are the steps i did:

Made a folder named `Testapk` in `packages/apps`
Copied apk to folder with name `Testapk.apk`
In same directory, created an `Android.mk` file with following contents:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := Testapk
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Testapk.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
TARGET_OUT_DATA_APPS_PRIVILEGED := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)/priv-app

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Then, added Testapk to `/build/target/product/base_system.mk`

Build is successful and i can see my apk in priv-app folder in `out/target/product/sdm660_64/system/priv-app`. After flashing, the device wont boot up. Its stuck on Android logo.

I am using Qualcom SDM660, the branch is android-10

If I add the apk to `system/apps`, i can boot and the apk works fine.

Can someone help me on this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shared the  Crash Stack here. Its difficult to tell.

I could see here that
Are you requesting any privileged permissions from the app side ? if yes, device will not boot until you whitelist those permissions in privileged permissions xml file which will be stored at either system/etc/permissions

Comment: Hi Ashok, How can I give all permissions to the app? https://justpaste.it/8zfs2 Saganakmdm its my app

Comment: Hi madinia, Can you share the Failure stack by running the command "logcat -b crash" ? so, i will get to know the privileged permissions which you are requesting

Comment: https://justpaste.it/9idbp Hi Ashok this is my output log. Please check. What should i do? Thank you @Ashok Mutyala

Comment: Please include below in this  file (justpaste.it/8zfs2) under "com.interprobe.saganakmdm"

<permission name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"/> 
<permission name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" 
<permission name="android.permission.RECOVERY"/>

Comment: Thank you the app is working. But I had a question for you, I want my app to never close. So I want to inactivate the force stop and disable buttons, how can I do that?

Comment: disable button is not enabled for System App and is not getting updated via server/PlayStore/ThirdPartyAppStore. Does your app falls under this ? For Force Stop, i will come back in your other question.